# Use of "whatever" vs "whatsoever"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

The city posts signs near my house that read:

> Dump no waste whatever

The meaning is clear in context: don't dump any waste here.  But the sign sounds incorrect.  To me, it seems "whatever" should be "whatsoever."  Is the sign correct?  Is it using an archaic form of "whatever"?

Comment: Does your city have a website that you can ask them about this? I agree that it would sound better with "whatsoever." Wonder why they didn't just say "No dumping."

Comment: The use of "whatever" for "whatsoever" is much more common in the British Isles than it is in America.  To some Americans, using "whatever" where they would have themselves used "whatsoever" sounds off/wrong/foreign.

Comment: But does anyone have a good explanation of *when* to use "whatsoever" in place of "whatever"?  To me, the questioner is right -- "whatever" sounds *wrong*, not merely less emphatic.

Comment: Every time I see this sign (in Seattle, WA) the exact same question pops into my mind.  I believe @user2683 is correct: there's no difference.  (Though he didn't cite any evidence.)  So now I believe the reason has more to do with the nature of city government employees:  Two fewer letters to paint in "whatever" vs "whatsoever". QED.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me as a British/Irish English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *[whatever](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whatever)* and *[whatsoever](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whatsoever)* may be used to mean *at all* for emphasis.

> Dump no waste at all.
>
> Dump no waste whatever.
>
> Dump no waste whatsoever.

Comment: Any source for your claim? Please

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a novice in this forum, I would like to take a shot at this.
Dude, I have to say this is a great question, as this really touches the psychology of the English language in the context of grammatical usage vs colloquial usage.

To me, *whatever* can be thought of as saying *what ever* in 2 cases.
1. Message without an emotion (literal meaning): *what ever* as in “whatever you do, do it right” or “Do whatever it takes”.
2. Message with an emotion: In movies, *whatever* is commonly used in completion of a sentence which carries a casual emotion to it. Like “I don't know, whatever”. Here the tagline of the script must be that the actor displays a feeling of neglect.

Whereas *whatsoever* is more formal. It is not archaic yet as far as I know. It carries the same meaning as *whatever*. To me, *whatsoever* cannot carry an emotion. It is more correct when used formally.

So, to answer your question, if the city's signpost said “dump no waste whatever”, then I would say it is wrong. It must have been just “dump no waste”.

Comment: It could be abbreviating the phrase "whatever occurs, Dump no waste".

Comment: No, that is not what it does. Both "whatever" and "whatsoever" here mean "at all".

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same - they both add emphasis. **Whatsoever** sounds more emphatic than **whatever**, but do you really need the extra emphasis? **Whatever** is in fact what educated writers in past centuries, like Churchill, mostly used. **Whatsoever** is mostly colloquial or American.

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is mostly colloquial, or American? Neither dictionary.com nor OED.com say that.

Comment: @MattЭллен “Neither” is plural?  Or OED.com?

Comment: Experience? Or does that not qualify?

Comment: It seems like a strange thing to say; in every other analogous form the "so" variant ("whosoever," "whensoever," etc.) is far more formal.  "Whatsoever" is much more frequently used than those, but I don't think it's more colloquial than "whatever."

Answer (score -1):

I hesitate to follow the logic of someone who starts his explanation with "Dude" (below), so I'll listen to brilliant lexicographer Bryan Garner who [says](http://www.lawprose.org/garners-usage-tip-of-the-day-whatever-whatsoever/):

> whatever; whatsoever.
>   Part A: Intensive Use.
>
> As an intensive (meaning “at all”), “whatsoever” is an established idiom in American English {he had no reason whatsoever}, though it is obsolescent in British English.
>
> Still, many American stylists prefer the shorter word, “whatever” — e.g.: “OPIC provides no grants or free benefits of any kind to any company or individual. None whatever.” Stuart E. Eizenstat, “‘Corporate Welfare’ or Savvy Policy?” Wash. Times, 23 July 1997, at A15.